# Process unexpectedly closed with status 1 with firefox webdrivers in watir (ruby on rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, watir

I have rails app with

```
gem 'headless'
gem 'watir'
gem 'webdrivers'
gem 'watir-screenshot-stitch'
gem 'watir-scroll'
```

i'm on debian 9, I have install `sudo apt-get install firefox-esr`

```
firefox-esr -v
Mozilla Firefox 52.9.0
```

I download lastest version of geckodrivers here https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases v0.21.0, I put drivers in `~/.webdrivers/`

but when I try start browser `browser = Watir::Browser.new :firefox, headless:true`

I got an imediate error :

```
Process unexpectedly closed with status 1

response.rb line 69 in assert_ok
response.rb line 32 in initialize
common.rb line 84 in new
common.rb line 84 in create_response
default.rb line 104 in request
common.rb line 62 in call
bridge.rb line 164 in execute
bridge.rb line 97 in create_session
driver.rb line 50 in initialize
driver.rb line 31 in new
driver.rb line 31 in new
driver.rb line 52 in for
webdriver.rb line 86 in for
```

I try purge and reinstall FF.

I try with v0.19.1 for geckodrivers

but nothing works and I don't know how to have more log to debug...

EDIT : with `Selenium::WebDriver.logger.level = :debug` I got :

```
DEBUG Selenium polling for socket on ["127.0.0.1", 4445]
App 1591 output: 1535219812449  geckodriver INFO    geckodriver 0.21.0
App 1591 output: 1535219812461  geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:4445 
App 1591 output: 2018-08-25 19:56:52 INFO Selenium Skipping handshake as we know it is W3C. 
App 1591 output: 2018-08-25 19:56:52 INFO Selenium
    -> POST session 
App 1591 output: 2018-08-25 19:56:52 INFO Selenium    >>> http://127.0.0.1:4445/session | {"desiredCapabilities":{"browserName":"firefox","version":"","platform":"ANY","javascriptEnabled":true,"cssSelectorsEnabled":true,"takesScreenshot":true,"nativeEvents":false,"rotatable":false,"moz:firefoxOptions":{"args":["--headless"]}},"capabilities":{"firstMatch":[{"browserName":"firefox","moz:firefoxOptions":{"args":["--headless"]}}]}} App 1591 output: 2018-08-25 19:56:52 DEBUG Selenium      > {"Accept"=>"application/json", "Content-Type"=>"application/json; charset=UTF-8", "User-Agent"=>"selenium/3.14.0 (ruby linux)", "Content-Length"=>"341"} App 1591 output: 1535219812709  mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "/usr/bin/firefox" "-marionette" "--headless" "-foreground" "-no-remote" "-profile" "/tmp/rust_mozprofile.ILvfKH3MZPFj" App 1591 output: Error: GDK_BACKEND does not match available displays App 1591 output: 2018-08-25 19:56:52 INFO Selenium <- {"value":{"error":"unknown error","message":"Process unexpectedly closed with status 1","stacktrace":""}}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think we've implemented headless for Firefox, yet. If you have xvfb installed on the machine you can use the headless gem.